# How to convert mySQL time to python time?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve time variable from mySQL database using python. Below shows the python code I use to retrieve the time variable from mySQL database.

```
import mysql.connector
import time
import datetime

con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='root',host='localhost',database='RV_Aquarium')

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("select Feed_Time from ActuatorsLog  ")

results = cur.fetchall()
delta = results[0]
print delta

cur.close()
```

I able to retrieve the data but it is in the format as shown below
[image]

I want to convert the retrieve data in the format, for example `19:00:00`. Can someone help me on how to convert from `(datetime.timedelta(0, 68400),)` to `19:00:00` format in python?

Below shows my database data ,

[image]

Comment: Do `print(delta[0])` and see what is outputted

Comment: Sure thing. For a better understand to why this is the case, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python). A little daunting, but boils down to how the value is being outputted

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the explanation aso bro! :D